# Getting different output for same operation in TF1 and TF2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to perform some matrix operations on a dataset and tried the same code both in TF1 and TF2.
But got different outputs.

**TF 2**

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing

housing = fetch_california_housing()
m,n = housing.data.shape
housing_data_plus_bias = np.c_[np.ones((m, 1)), housing.data]
X = tf.constant(housing_data_plus_bias, dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
y = tf.constant(housing.target.reshape(-1, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name="y")
XT = tf.transpose(X)
theta = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.linalg.inv(tf.matmul(XT, X)), XT), y)

tf.print(theta)
```

**Output:**

```
[[-36.8962631]
 [0.436777472]
 [0.0094444938]
 ...
 [-0.00378797273]
 [-0.420847952]
 [-0.434020907]]
```

**TF 1:**

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
housing = fetch_california_housing()
m, n = housing.data.shape
housing_data_plus_bias = np.c_[np.ones((m, 1)), housing.data]
X = tf.constant(housing_data_plus_bias, dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
y = tf.constant(housing.target.reshape(-1, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name="y")
XT = tf.transpose(X)
theta = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.matrix_inverse(tf.matmul(XT, X)), XT), y)


with tf.Session() as sess:
 theta_value = theta.eval()

theta_value
```

**Output:**

```
array([[-3.68962631e+01],
       [ 4.36777472e-01],
       [ 9.44449380e-03],
       [-1.07348785e-01],
       [ 6.44962370e-01],
       [-3.94082872e-06],
       [-3.78797273e-03],
       [-4.20847952e-01],
       [-4.34020907e-01]], dtype=float32)
```

Is it a bug? Or a mistake in my code?

Answer (score 2):

It is neither a bug nor a mistake - these are the exact same results, only in the second case they are written in the so-called [E-notation](https://stattrek.com/statistics/dictionary.aspx?definition=e-notation): a floating number ending in `e+01` means multiplication by `10^1`, so `-3.68962631e+01` is equal to `-36.8962631`; similarly, `e-03` means multiplication by `10^(-3)` (i.e. division by `10^3=1000`), so `-3.78797273e-03` is equal to `-0.00378797273`etc.

Not difficult to check it formally with the results you show:

```
import numpy as np

# your TF2 results:
a = np.array([[-36.8962631],
              [0.436777472],
              [0.0094444938],
              [-0.00378797273],
              [-0.420847952],
              [-0.434020907]])

# your TF1 results:    
b = np.array([[-3.68962631e+01],
              [ 4.36777472e-01],
              [ 9.44449380e-03],
              [-3.78797273e-03],
              [-4.20847952e-01],
              [-4.34020907e-01]])

np.all(a==b)
# True
```